# How to take multi-GPU support to the OpenNMT-py (pytorch)?

Tags: python-2.7, pytorch, opennmt

I used python-2.7 version to run the PyTorch with GPU support. I used this command to train the dataset using multi-GPU. 
Can someone please tell me how can I fix this error with PyTorch in OpenNMT-py or is there a way to take pytorch support for multi-GPU using python 2.7?

Here is the command that I tried.

> > CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1,2
> >     python train.py -data data/demo -save_model demo-model -world_size 2 -gpu_ranks 0 1

This is the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "train.py", line 200, in 
>     main(opt)
>   File "train.py", line 60, in main
>   mp = torch.multiprocessing.get_context('spawn')
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_context'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check whether your torch and python versions fit the openmt requiremen.
I remember their torch is 1.0 or 1.2 (1.0 is better). You have to lower your latest of version of torch. Hope that would work